Using Libcurl and C++ , program not fetching content from the website
My program seems to make a http request but apparently is not fetching content.
I am trying to fetch the content of the web every second , store it and compare it to see if the content fetched is any different.
i cout the fetcehd content and on console nothing shows. so the content is not getting fetcehd properly . please help why is that
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <Windows.h> // Include Windows API header for playing sound


using namespace std;



int sum=0;

//function to play sound
void playSound() {
    // Play sound using Windows API (Beep function)
    Beep(1000, 500); // Beep at 1000 Hz for 500 milliseconds
}


//the orifinal code before 
/*
// Function to perform HTTP request and fetch page content
static string fetchPageContent(const string& url) {
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    string content;


    cout << "Making HTTP request to: " << url << endl;// making sure request is made

    // Initialize libcurl
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        // Set URL to fetch
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        // Set write callback function to store fetched content
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, [](void* buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp) -> size_t {
            ((string*)userp)->append((char*)buffer, size * nmemb);
            return size * nmemb;
            });
        // Set userp parameter to point to content string
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);
        // Perform HTTP request
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        // Clean up
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }



    cout << "Fetched HTML content:" << endl;
    cout << content << endl; // Print fetched HTML content

    return content;
}
*/

//the new one to see why no content fetched 
// Function to perform HTTP request and fetch page content
static string fetchPageContent(const string& url) {
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    string content;

    cout << "Making HTTP request to: " << url << endl;

    // Initialize libcurl
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        // Set URL to fetch
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

        // Set SSL certificate verification
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

        // Set user agent string
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99 Safari/537.36");

        // Set timeout values
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); // 10 seconds timeout
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); // 5 seconds connect timeout

        // Set write callback function to store fetched content
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, [](void* buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp) -> size_t {
            ((string*)userp)->append((char*)buffer, size * nmemb);
            return size * nmemb;
            });
        // Set userp parameter to point to content string
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);

        // Perform HTTP request
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        // Check for errors
        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            cerr << "Error during HTTP request: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << endl;
        }

        // Clean up
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    cout << "Fetched HTML content:" << endl;
    cout << content << endl; // Print fetched HTML content

    return content;
}


// Function to parse HTML content and detect changes
bool parsePageContent(const string& previousContent, const string& currentContent) {
    // Compare previous and current HTML content
    return previousContent != currentContent;
}

/*the path adding of libcurl is done and now we have no errors in the basic layout code. 
Next step is to check if the data is getting parsed by adding the link. 
then we check if the logic is working( we have two logics) 
then I would have to create a same copy form web of my own. update it and see if the program is working 
or not. 
*/
int main() {

    string appointmentPageUrl = "https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/setup#non-administrative-install";



    // Initialize previous HTML content
    string previousContent = "";

    // Main monitoring loop
    while (true) {
        // Fetch current page content
        string currentContent = fetchPageContent(appointmentPageUrl);

        // Parse page content and check for changes
        if (parsePageContent(previousContent, currentContent)) {
            // Display message in console if appointments are open
            cout << "open!" << endl;
            playSound();
            while (true)
            {  
                cout << "  open!  ";
                playSound();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sum = sum + 1;
            cout << sum;
            system("cls");
            
        }
          //  system("cls");
            
        // Update previous HTML content
        previousContent = currentContent;

        // Sleep for a certain period before next check (e.g., 1 second)
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    }

    return 0;
}


I expect someone to tell me why my code is not fetching the content of the webiste .

Capture and inspect the result codes for curl_easy_setopt and curl_easy_perform. If you don't check for and handle detectable errors, you'll waste time debugging those errors.

Side note: When the Ask-a-question wizard prompts you for your  expectations, what they want you to do is go through your expectations for the program and highlight where the discrepancies with the reality are. Stating that you expect to get an answer to your question is self-evident from asking the question, and doesn't add anything useful to the question. Yes, the wording of the prompt is garbage and we've been trying to get it cleaned up for quite a while now.

Offhand, I don't see anything wrong with the code that would cause the content to be empty. You are going to have to dig deeper with a debugger to figure out what is going on. That being said, as an optimization you might consider sending a HEAD request first and check for changes in the Last-Modified response header before then sending a full GET request for new content. Or, save the last checked Date header and then include an If-Modified-Since header in your GET request. The response code will be 304 if the content hasn't changed, or 200 if it has.

Your commented-out code varies significantly from the code that doesn't work - you now use SSL, for example. Check for all status results, as others have suggested.

Can I use libcurls CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION with a C++11 lambda expression? may be relevant.

@user4581301 Thanks brother it helped.
also would keep in mind your sidenote for next time.
